# How to scrape web data in R that requires clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping

So I'm new to web scraping, and wanted to learn by trying to scrape the keurig website for fun, and extracting information about some of the k cups for sale. My goal is to go to the k-cups page, click on every k-cup and extract some information such as if it is caffeinated, the roast color, and maybe origin. I can tackle that stuff later, I'm having some trouble finding the CSS or finding a way to automate the process of clicking every object to get the extra info. I did this:

```
library(rvest)
keurig <- read_html("http://www.keurig.com/beverages/k-cup-pods")
# Grab the CSS Nodes from the website
keurig.html <- html_nodes(keurig, ".keurig_card")
keurig.text <- html_text(keurig.html)
# Print the text
keurig.text
```

I ended up getting a lot of tab and new line characters with some of the coffee names in between. How exactly would I scrape this data to grab the info about every k-cup?

Comment: If it is unstructured data (I cannot access Keurig.com at the moment), you would have to use Regular Expressions. see here for a good introduction: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1123/pattern-matching-and-replacement#t=201707310419474805317    I guess that regular expressions in connection with CSS-Tags might work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the links for every item:

```
library(rvest)
keurig <- read_html("http://www.keurig.com/beverages/k-cup-pods")
keurig.html <- html_nodes(keurig, ".product_name")
links = html_attr(keurig.html, name = "href")
```

The class that contains the links to every item is `product_name`.
Once you get the nodes, extract the `href` property.

**Result** (first four shown):

```
 [1] "/Beverages/Coffee/Regular/Breakfast-Blend-Coffee/p/Breakfast-Blend-Coffee-K-Cup-Green-Mountain"                          
 [2] "/Beverages/Coffee/Regular/Dark-Magic%C2%AE-Extra-Bold-Coffee/p/Dark-Magic-Extra-Bold-Coffee-K-Cup-Green-Mountain"        
 [3] "/Beverages/Coffee/Regular/The-Original-Donut-Shop%C2%AE-Coffee/p/Original-Donut-Shop-Extra-Bold-Coffee-K-Cup-CP"         
 [4] "/Beverages/Coffee/Regular/Nantucket-Blend%C2%AE-Coffee/p/Nantucket-Blend-Coffee-K-Cup-Green-Mountain"
```

Then use `paste0` to create the link to each cake's details page:

```
paste0("http://www.keurig.com/beverages/k-cup-pods", 
       "/Beverages/Coffee/Regular/Breakfast-Blend-Coffee/p/Breakfast-Blend-Coffee-K-Cup-Green-Mountain")
```

Comment: I tried to use this but when try to read the text inside the link with `html_text`I get the following error (`Error in UseMethod("xml_text") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_text' applied to an object of class "character"`) any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: @Rollo99 Try `linkText = html_text(keurig.html)`